# Hg workflow with two different release cycles

Tags: mercurial, workflow, dvcs, release-management

We're about to change our workflow for our release management as part of our upgrade from a CVCS (TFS) to DVCS (Hg). Some things have been discussed pretty intense here at office and I would be glad to get some input about it.

**Some background**

We're a small/midsized software company (approx. 25 developers) with a long lived product. We try to keep our release cycles low - a release after each sprint (~once a month). In TFS we create a branch for each new release. The two last releases supports bug fixes.

*Our current branch model (TFS)*

```
--trunk
  --release200 //and older, not supported anymore
  --release201
  --release202
```

On top of these branches we have different developer branches (if needed). Some team branches and some feature branches.

"Small" bugs are corrected on release202 and merged to trunk. Critical bugs are corrected on release201 and merged to release 202 and trunk.

What we don't support is bug fixes on older releases.

**New workflow**

Some customers don't care that much about new features, instead they want a more stable version. Therefore we are thinking about offering two tracks - one long lived release with patches, another with more frequent updates of features.
We've been thinking about having branches like this...

(Hg)

```
--default
  --RC
  --Release
  --StableRelease200
  --StableRelease210
```

These are all named branches inside a central Hg repository. Each of these branches is connected to a CI machine. From a developer perspective, there will be develop branches (hg clones) outside the scope of this question.

Some customers will use releases from Release, some from StableReleaseX.

**Default:** All new development of features is merged into this branch.

**RC:** When a PBI is done/end of a sprint, default is merged into this branch for internal testing. Bugs found in this branch is also corrected here. When QA thinks it's stable enough, this branch is merged into Release. If some developers need continue to work on new features, they can do it on Default.

**Release:** Releases here happens sequentially, only the last one will support bug fixes. From a technical perspective, releases are marked with Hg Tags. Critical bugs found at customer site during a sprint will be fixed here and merged back to default.

**StableReleases:** Every half year or so (decided by management), Release is merged to a new StableRelease branch. During its life time, no new features will be added here. Bugs found here will be fixed here and merged back all the way to default. Probably two StableReleases will be supported at the same time - the current one and the second last. Older branches will be closed.

**Some questions**

- General opinions about the workflow? Do you have any experience in supporting two different, concurrent "release tracks"? One with frequent releases and one with long lived releases with bug fixes only?
- We’ve been thinking having the branches as named branches to make it easier for the developer (one VS, one pull etc). Or... do you think it will be harder? Easier to have seperate clones instead (most of the developers have limited experience using a DVCS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [wiki page on "standard" branching](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching) in the Mercurial wiki. You'll be glad to learn that it describes a workflow very similar to the one you propose! :-) So yes, having two release tracks like this works very well.

As for using named branches instead of clones, then we're very happy with the two names branches we use in the Mercurial project itself. We used to have two repositories, but now have a `default` and a `stable` branch.

The reason why some prefer separate clones on the server is that it might give a better overview: the "branches" then show up as separate repositories.

Comment: About the link... Yes, it describes nicely how to support multiple versions. We also want to have a possibility to release more often to some customer but anyhow - that link gives nice input.
About named branches vs clones... As you write, our concern about many named branches (we will have 3 + noOfStableReleases) will make the "overview" a bit more complex.)

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You can make the clones on the server-side too if you like and synchronize them with a cronjob or similar. We have that for Mercurial too: http://selenic.com/repo/hg and http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg-stable

Comment: Yes. I'll think we'll start with named branches.
Thanks for your input.